# I want to add products to my web page from database but in a custom div that I already have (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have this problem where I created a shopping site with ASP.NET, but I want to when a client adds a product I want that product to be in a special div that I created that contains the image and the description of the product and the price and when they click on it they go to a blank page that contains all the info of that product.

I don't know how to show information from the database in a div, I only show it in gridview that's all I know plus I want when they search a product the result will be shown in the same way.

```
*****UPDATE*****
//this is what i tried for now but it didnt work it
 //This is my query  
SELECT img, Détails FROM Produit WHERE (id_Prod = @id_Prod).
//And this is what im trying now  
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="reptater">
<ItemTemplate<section<asp:HyperLinkID="HyperLink1"runat="server"NavigateUrl="~/Accueil.aspx"> <div class="gallery"><asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="<%#Eval("img") %>"runat="server"width="600"height="400"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<div class="desc"><%#Eval("Détails") %></div> </div> </asp:HyperLink> </section></ItemTemplate></asp:Repeater>.
// c# : 
 reptater.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
            reptater.DataBind();
```

Answer (score -1):

In your controller that you update to database, you will return a view with the model that contains a list of updated itens.

```
public ActionResult AssignTask() 
{
    var model = db.Employees.Select(x => new EmployeeViewModel
    { 
        ID = x.id, 
        Name = x.Name
    }).ToList();

    return View(model);
}
```

Your new view.

```
@model List<EmployeeViewModel>

<h2>AssignTask</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div style="overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:hidden; height:400px;">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                    <label>@item.Name</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="SelectEmp" value="@item.ID" />
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have tried this and it almost works look up i updated